# DOB field as date tab prompts date picker

Tags: docusignapi

I have a date field and it has to be a date field as I need to run formula on the field to identify is the person is over 18 or not. Formula field is to find if dob is 18 or over. And date formula's does not work on text field.

Now the issue is, because it is a date field, docusign prompts date picker and any date format I provide either through validation or by changing the regional setting does not change the date format. It is always 2021-06-24T12:00:00-04:00 (ie YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS).

Date tab gets added using API and so are the validationPattern. Please can you help me with the following issues.

1. How can I stop the date picker from showing?
2. Even if the date picker shows up, how to control the date format. I am looking for mm/dd/yyyy
3. Regional settings, Time Zone does not have a Date format without timestamp. Inspite of picking  something from there, date picker does not match what was picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update,** you can use formulateTab to calculate the date in 18 years like this:

```
AddYears( [Text <GUID>] , 18)
```

Note  above is the unique ID of the text tab where the user enters their DOB.

Hope that helps.

Make it into a text field and you can then just use Date validation with one of the formats below: (make sure it works for you first from the web app - you can later do this all with the eSign API)

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works from admin console but not via API.
When the dob is created as text field and forrmula field with DateDiff([today18],[dob]) is applied, docusign fails to recognize dob as date field.
But if dob is changed to date field the same formula works.
Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body: '{"errorCode":"INVALID_TAB_FORMULA","message":"The Tab formula is not valid. Tab Formula for tab, diff18 is invalid. Formula = if (DateDiff([today18],[dob])>0,0,1): [dob] is not a valid field."}'
How to specify validation Date in textTab?

Comment: please share the code that does not work and I can try to help fix it.

Comment: ```Text text = new Text();
//Date text = new Date();
text.setDocumentId("1");
text.setName("dob");
text.setTabLabel("dob");
text.setValidationPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
text.setRequired("true");
tabs.addTextTabsItem(text);
 //tabs.addDateTabsItem(text);
FormulaTab formulaTab = new FormulaTab();
formulaTab.setDocumentId("1");
formulaTab.setFormula("AddDays([dob],-365.24*18)");
formulaTab.setName("diff18");
formulaTab.setTabLabel("diff18");
tabs.addFormulaTabsItem(formulaTab);
```
This is how the tab is created

Comment: Html for the document

```
<div>
    <div >
        <div >
            <div >
                <div >&nbsp;{{dated1}}</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div >{{"type":"text","tabLabel":"dob","width":120,"validationPattern":"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{"type":"formula","tabLabel":"today18","formula":"AddDays([dateSigned1]$-365.24*18)"}}
        {{"type":"formula","tabLabel":"diff18","formula":"if (DateDiff([today18]$[dob])>0$0$1)"}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure you can do something like that. It seems to me you want some text filed to have a value that is based on when the envelope was signed. This will require a more advanced capability. One way would be pause the envelope BEFORE it's complete and use a webhook and update the envelope with the value you want from another API call done dynamically when the envelope reached the state when you know the date. Let me know if you want more details on all of this. But to be clear you want the date to be set automatically to some calculated value that is based on when exactly someone signed, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.. My whole intention is to find if a person is 18 years old or not.
1. Capture dob 
2. find 18 years from the date signed (datesigned - 365.24*18)
3. check if dob is less than or greater than the value from step 2.

Unless there is a better/smatter way to find 18 years or older that I am not aware of.

Comment: hmmm, something doesn't make sense in what you just said.
Date signed is not date of birth.
What you are asking is to find the date entered, the value that was entered and calculate 18 years later. 
That can be done using a formula, but you should not be using dateSigned, that's the date something is signed, not the date that was entered.

Comment: Let me add something to my answer to try to help...

Comment: Thanks for the update. Issue is if dob is date then the formula works but if the dob is not a date then the formula does not work. 
formulaTab.setFormula("AddYears([dob],18)"); 
AddYears([dob],18): [dob] is not a valid field. -- when dob is text
If dob is a date field then the date picker shows and also users can enter date skipping date picker. In this date format is not consistent.

Comment: yes, you have to have a date to use things like AddYears, it won't make sense otherwise.

Comment: so, if you want:
1. Date field that does not use date picker
2. Formula field doing date calculation on #1

You can't do that using regular tools of DocuSign.

Comment: This works when done from console. But not through the API. Ie create a text field and set the validation to Date and the validation pattern to MM/dd/yyyy. Formula works with that field. Can this be requested as an enhancement for API?

And finally want to thank you for following up the ticket and reading every bit of my response. Best experience for me.

Comment: everything you can do from "console" (web app) - you can do from API.
I'm not clear what you did, but here is a tip - you can record all the API calls that are made in the web app and see what APIs were made when you did it and do the same from you app.

Comment: To do that - go to your developer account (the web app) and from the top-right menu select "Preferences" and then click "Enable Logging"
Then do what you did that worked from the web app
come back here and you can download API logs that show exactly what API were called.
The DocuSign web app is using the API just like any other integration...

Comment: That was the best tip and how did I not know about it all this time. It is going to be a game changed. And i just learnt the issue which was the validationpattern on the date object when using date picker. I cannot thank you enough. You are amazing.